# Wrong product URLs magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I've been working on custom up sells related products script, which is displaying 4 random products.

Problem is:

normal product url is:

/shop/$productname

This sometimes is generating url like: /$productname/

or url like: /catalog/product/view/id/$productID/4/s/$productname/category/$categoryid/

I want to have all my URLs the same so: /shop/$productname

```
<div class="upsell">
<h2>You might be interested in</h2>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <?php // Grid Mode ?>
    <table class="products-grid upsell" id="upsell-product-table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); $_columnCount=4; ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <?php endif ?>
            <td>
            <?php // Initiate product model
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

// Load specific product whose tier price want to update
$product ->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(170); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                 <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($product, $product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product, true) ?>

            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$this->getUrl('shop').$product->getUrlPath()
```

instead of

```
$product->getProductUrl()
```

for both image and product title.

Answer (score 0):

If your indexes are up to date then

```
$product->getProductUrl()
```

Should give you the correct product url.
Do not try to build the url yourself from pieces like the url_key, or url_path and the base url. If you move your website to an other serve you're going to have some issues. Also if you change the config settings for categories in product url you can have problems.

Comment: My indexes seems up to date, but it's not working, just part of the links are working properly, can deleting of all rewrites url solve it? and create them again?

Comment: You can try it, but back-up first.

Comment: Cleared all rewrites, still same issue.